# Simple animation library in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to create animations on a canvas. 
They are similar to animating `top` on an element.

I want the simplest possible library for animations.
Ideally I would like to send in `duration`, `easing` and a function which gets called with a percent.

I've tried [`Animator.js`](http://berniesumption.com/software/animator/) which does what I want but it is unmaintained and is quite laggy.

Most libraries I've seen are over 10k minified and do pretty much everything except what I want.

Are there any good, small and efficient libraries for this out there or am I going to have to write one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JSTweener

This is a very light one I use. The only thing I would like added to it is removeTweens(...).

Comment: Nice! I really like that you can animate properties on any object. This means I could spoof the percent. Or even better, just animate the `top` directly.

Comment: Worked flawlessly, awesome lib. Thanks!